# Node JS Mongodb insert command

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, mongodb

I am currently trying to write a simple node.js app to grab data from the Pokemon TCG website using their API and a module designed around it.
I am able to get information back from the API (this stores it in a json style array). I then iterate through the array to add all of the documents to a MongoDB container that I have running on my machine atm.

my code is as follows;

```
const pokemon = require('pokemontcgsdk');
var prompt = require('prompt');
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var databaseconnect = 'mongo://localhost:27017/';


prompt.start();

prompt.get(['setcodein'], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result.setcodein);
    var settosearch = result.setcodein;
    pokemon.card.where({ supertype: 'Trainer', setCode: settosearch })
    .then(results => {
        for(i =0;i < results.length;i++){
            console.log(results[i].name);
            mongo.connect(databaseconnect, function(err, db){
                var dbo = db.db("pokemon");
                dbo.collection("trainer").insertOne(result[i], function(err, r){
                    console.log('Card Added to database');
                    db.close();
                })
            })
        }
    })
});
```

when I run the code I get the following error;

```
prompt: setcodein:  sm9
sm9
Bill's Analysis
(node:5090) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option {
 useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of null
    at /Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/index.js:19:30
    at err (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:415:14)
    at executeCallback (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:404:25)
    at executeOperation (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:422:7)
    at MongoClient.connect (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:168:10)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:372:22)
    at pokemon.card.where.then.results (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/index.js:18:19)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:51
2:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/elliottbuckingham/Google Drive/Coding/Java/Pokemon App/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

I have tried different methods of connecting. I have also tried adding in err throws but the errors come out more or less the same.

The pokemon DB and the trainer collection are all created. But there is no documents in the database.

I am doing something obvious wrong

kind Regards
Elliott

Comment: var dbo=db.db() is the culprit .Why dont you try it  the way it's mentioned in the documentation: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone. I have tired a combination of rewriting the code from the github and then also using the

```
 { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Statement.

This has fixed my issue. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Check your mongo version

```
mongo --version
```

If you are using version >= 3.1.0 change you mongo connection file to ->

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })
or your mongoose connection file to ->

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Ideally, it's a version 4 feature but v3.1.0 and above is supporting it too. Check out MongoDB Github for details.

Answer (score 0):

To connect `mongodb`

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost:27017, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```